# Shouldn't "won't work" and other synonyms be barred from question titles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For most cases that I've encountered, questions with the title "won't work", "not working", "doesn't compile", and so forth, are often questions that one would vote to close as "not a real question", or "too localized" - namely due to the way the question was framed.  The title itself may lend credence to the issue, but "won't work" [isn't really a question in itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/175248).

Stackoverflow already forbids some words in its titles which would produce low-quality questions.  Would there be any reason not to extend that feature to these words/synonyms?

- won't work
- doesn't work
- not working
- won't compile
- broken code

Comment: I'd love it if this were possible but I'm worried that you'd get "won work" or "dint work" instead

Comment: I look forward to titles like `borken c0de`

Comment: Also its really easy to find counter examples [Simple Linq expression won't compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245012/simple-linq-expression-wont-compile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of disallowing specific words in titles is to encourage people to *write better titles* to otherwise good questions.  If the majority of those questions should just be closed and deleted then that's the action that should be taken.  Blocking these words and phrases would just make bad questions harder to spot and deal with.

In addition to that, blocking certain words from being used in titles has proven to be very unpopular in the past.  In order to get more words blocked, I think you'd have to show that the *vast* majority of titles that use those words are not helpful at all.

See also: [The Efficacy Of Stack Overflow's Question Title Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113151/1288)

Comment: Fair enough.  I can respect that.