# Block “{{tag}} question” and similar as a question title

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter, question-restrictions

#### Proposal

At least once a day, I see a question titled with something along the lines of:

> dynamical systems question
>   Photoshop issue
>   publication problem

where the first part of the title is also a tag of the question. These question titles do not provide any information that cannot be found in the tags and thus are maximally useless. From another point of view, such a title would be equally (badly) fitting to every single question in said tag.
I propose that such titles are blocked automatically, i.e., the asker cannot post the question and is shown a notice urging them to choose a better title.

#### Specific criterion

Barring punctuation and grammatical number, the title is one of:

> [tag] [buzzword]
>   [buzzword] [preposition] [tag]

where:

- *tag* is a tag applied to the question or a synonym thereof
- *buzzword* is *question, issue, problem, …*
- *preposition* is *about, on, with …*

#### Notes

- A much stricter version of this filter (banning *question* and *problem* from titles altogether) exists on Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault.
  This is not what I propose here.
  In contrast to these filters, I cannot imagine a false positive for this filter, i.e., a good title that would be blocked.
- I am aware that some stubborn idiot will find a way around this filter – they are not my target group.
  My target group are askers who see the error of their ways and change their title to something more informative.
  Going by [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113151/255554), such askers do exist.

Comment: Somewhat related: a similar [warning for titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17012) exists on Math. If your "dynamical systems question" example was from there, it should have triggered a warning (which apparently did not help). Linking the filter to tags makes it a dev effort; a static filter like on Math could be added by a CM.

Comment: @bro: Thanks. Yes, I do not have the feeling that that filter on Math SE is that effective, e.g., consider [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A+%22trigonometry+question%22) – but then it’s hard to tell how bad things would be without it. While I agree that my suggestion would be more difficult to implement, it is sufficiently specific to warrant a red instead of a yellow warning, which at least forces people to be creative to circumvent it.

Comment: Tying this to tags, besides increasing the investment required, also decreases the return on that investment: maybe "Dynamical systems question" matches, but "Dynamical system question" or "ODE system question" do not, despite not being any better. I think a cheaper and more general heuristic would be: title consists of <=3 words one of which is `doubt|issue|problem|query|question`.

Comment: @bro: I did account for grammatical number in my proposal (and so can an algorithm). — The problem of the cheaper heuristic is that it also tends to produce false positives.