# Stack Overflow forbids usage of the word `help` in question about CLI `--help` option

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, asking-questions, title

A question title I wanted to submit got rejected because it ended with `help?`:

```
How do I get typer to accept the short `-h` as well as the long `--help` for help?
```

I was told:

> Your question couldn't be submitted. Resolve 1 issues [sic!] before posting
> These words are not allowed in titles 'help?'.. See Writing Good Titles

The question was about the `help` option of a CLI tool. So this looks like a false positive to me.

[image]

Would it be possible to improve the filter, maybe make it dependent on reputation? Maybe users above a certain threshold should be warned and not prohibited from asking questions containing words like `help` since they usually know what they are doing.

PS: It should say `1 issue` not `1 issues` in the box on the right hand side. Also, not sure why the red error message has a double period `..` not a single `.` or triple period `...` after `'help?'`. I don't think a double period is ever used in English.

PPS: I found this relevant meta post that seems to suggest that at least 2 years ago, only 4 users with >10k reputation had ever hit that particular filter. Hardly believable: [The Efficacy Of Stack Overflow's Question Title Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter?rq=1). Well, now I'm user 5. Interesting that there has not been any significant change to this in 10 years. See e.g. [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so). Another useful post from 10 years ago: [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles?rq=1)

PPPS: I agree that the final "help" isn't crucial in this title. But in this case one would need to rewrite for no reason: `How do I get Typer to accept "-h" to output CLI help?`. One workaround is to wrap it in backticks but there should be no need for such a workaround.

Comment: _"Get typer to accept the `-h` switch in addition to `--help`"_ ???

Comment: Sure, could rephrase like that - but the usage of the word `help` is not intrinsically problematic. This is the filter getting in the way where it shouldn't. And who knows, maybe Google doesn't see `--help` when people google `Typer CLI short option for help`

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer pretty sure Google would be able to handle the '--', but I agree you should be able to use the actual word "help"

Comment: @Esther Agreed, but depending on the ratio of proper question titles and the prevention of bad titles (but that ratio seems pretty low seeing the first linked thread in the post here..).

Comment: @Joachim it seems like SO isn't open to modifications to the filter system, which most likely *does* help most of the time, but clearly fails in situations like this.

Comment: In this specific case, though, does the ending `for help?` really add any meaningful context? I don't think it adds any value over `How do I get typer to accept the short \`-h\` as well as the long \`--help\``? I don't think it adds any _additional_ disambiguation about what `-h` is for.

Comment: I agree that in this particular case the word `help` isn't essential but this has nothing to do with the fact that `help` is often used in bad titles/questions. One should look again at the data to see how common good/bad/neutral changes after the error are - 10 years after the last survey where there wasn't enough data to say anything about >2k reputation users.

Comment: I think the "For help?" at the end is the issue. Remove that? Or add to beginning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111098/282094)

Comment: I don't understand why someone voted to close this as "Relates to only one specific network site". This happens on several sites, including Stack Overflow and Super User.